# How to get mean of all elements in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame that contains 150 numerical values that I want the mean of. Which column or row they're on is not relevant at all, that's just how the data was given.

I have found a solution to do this, but it's so shamefully disgusting that I'd prefer to use a better method. I've literally just added up the mean of each column and divided by the number of columns...

This is still a 1-liner so it's not that bad, but there must be better ways to do this.

A thousand thanks in advance!

Comment: Does not work. I get the following error: `In mean.default(d) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA `

Comment: You can't pass a data frame to `mean()`.  It needs to be unlisted first `mean(unlist(df))`.

Comment: @H 1 Thank you, that makes sense. Used the unlist() function and it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for me was to unlist it with the unlist() function. Thanks to @H 1 !

Then you can simply use the mean() function.